# What is this variable declaration with underscore, inline interface and assignment?

Tags: syntax, go

What does this snippet of Go code do?

```
var _ interface {
    add(string) error
} = &watcher{}
```

I believe `&watcher{}` returns two things, the first is discarded and the second is assigned to ... an interface? I found the code in [fswatch](https://github.com/davecheney/fswatch/blob/master/fswatch_test.go) on Github.

Comment: It looks more like a static "structural type" check - e.g. it will fail to compile (fail early, fail fast) if an incompatible type is attempted to be assigned. I do not believe there is any "unpacking" occuring. (But I do not use Go.)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414917/1153938

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This construct will declare a variable with an [blank identifier](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) name with type given by a type literal; an interface definition in this case. What follows is in initializer expression - a pointer to a composite literal in this case.

Overall functionality of the snippet is to statically ensure that a `*watcher` satisfies the said interface as the `_` variable is not materialized in any way and only any possible side effects of the initializer can be observed. Either static (as in this case) or dynamic (like e.g. calling a function which assigns at runtime to, say, some global vars, registers a handler, etc.)