# Have trouble understanding a piece of golang code

Tags: methods, go, interface

```
package main

type Writeable interface {
    OnWrite() interface{}
}

type Result struct {
    Message string
}

func (r *Result) OnWrite() interface{} {
    return r.Message
}

// what does this line mean? what is the purpose?
var _ Writeable = (*Result)(nil)


func main() {

}
```

The comments in the code snippet expressed my confusion.
As I understood, the line with comment notifies the compiler to check whether a struct  has implemented the interface, but I am not sure very much.  Could someone help explaining the purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this variable declaration with underscore, inline interface and assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202181/what-is-this-variable-declaration-with-underscore-inline-interface-and-assignme)

Answer (score 7):

As you say it's a way to verify that `Result` implements `Writeable`. From the [GO FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#guarantee_satisfies_interface):

> You can ask the compiler to check that the type T implements the
>   interface I by attempting an assignment:
>
> ```
> type T struct{} 
> var _ I = T{}   // Verify that T implements I.
> ```

The blank identifier _ stands for the variable name which is not needed here (and thus prevents a "declared but not used" error).

`(*Result)(nil)` creates an uninitialized pointer to a value of type `Result` by [converting](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) `nil` to `*Result`. This avoids allocation of memory for an empty struct as you'd get with `new(Result)` or `&Result{}`.